# Why change xml file in Eclipse project will trigger project auto build

Tags: xml, eclipse, build

If there is a xml file in a Eclipse java project, and with "build Automatically" enabled, every time I change the xml file, and save, it will trigger Eclipse to build the project, and sometimes it cause much time to finish.

I just thought that xml files are just resource files, or at least it is not code change and should not trigger project build. What's the reason for this, and is there anyway to disable it?

Answer (score 5):

You are right there xml files are resource files. If the project code depends on the xml listed resource and there is some change in the xml file, auto build gets triggered to verify if the valid resource is available to the project, if not it shows warnings, or errors as the case may be.

To stop auto build in Eclipse:
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Uncheck the checkbox 'Build automatically'

Comment: Yes, it is right the way I am using now to resolve this problem. as sometimes the build will cause quite some time to finish, and block my work.

Comment: Fine. Yes if its a large project, auto build can slow down the development/debugging. Now what is the question you have?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a option to avoid xml save build while leaving "build automatically" selected, or say I just want to know if there is an option in the config of Eclipse somewhere can do the job. Maybe there is just how Eclipse builder works and no way to change.

Comment: You can try 1) Project > un-check the check box 'Build Automatically'. See if it stops all the auto build activities. 2) Window > Preferences > Validation > choose XML Validator . Then click on Setting [..] button and Remove 'File extension: xml' from 'Include Group' and add it in 'Exclude Group'. Do remember this change so that you can revert back when you actually want this back. :)

Answer (score 4):

I finally find out a workaround to this problem:

go to project properties > Java Build Path > Source > add an exclude rule: ****/*.xml

by excluding all xml files from Java Build Path, now edit xml files will not trigger build with 'build Automatically' on.

Comment: but if the xml present outside the source folder and even then if it build automatically ??

Answer (score 2):

From Eclipse documentation,

```
A build is a process that derives new resources from existing ones, updates existing 
resources, or both
```

It is not just compilation of source code

Comment: ok, so this is not a problem. Maybe I need to check why it costs quite some time to finish the build invoked by xml change.

Comment: @moonese. I think xml validator is turned on - this can cause a delay.

Comment: If I don't change anything, the project has been built successfully, and then I make some change to an xml file, and save, then sometime I can see that some java source file is being built again in the progress pane. Since it doesn't happen every time, I'd better keep an eye on this and see if I can find more information.